# react useCallback hook unexpected behavior on re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-hooks

Maybe I just don't get how hooks are supposed to work, but I have tried many different configurations to convert this component to hooks and they all fail.

```
export const VideoContainer = ({ localStream, remoteStream, status }: Props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const setLocalStreamEl = useCallback(node => {
    console.log('useCallback');
    if (localStream && node && !node.srcObject) {
      console.log('setting srcObject');
      node.srcObject = localStream;
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <InjectIntl>
      {intl =>
        localStream && remoteStream && status === intl.messages.inProgress ? (
          <div className={classes.videoDiv}>
            render something else
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div className={classes.videoDiv}>
            <video ref={setLocalStreamEl} className={classes.mainStream} autoPlay controls />
          </div>
        )
      }
    </InjectIntl>
  );
};
```

I get the video element rendering with the video stream, but the status prop gets renewed every second and on a re-render it calls all of the `useCallback` logic and it causes the video to flicker annoyingly.

I have tried adding a `useRef` callback, and different combinations of what is below and `useEffect`, and I've read through the docs 100 times but I can't fit all the pieces together in a way that works and doesn't reset the ref on every render.

Any ideas?

Comment: `}, [localStream]);` ?

Comment: I tried that as well and it still renders on every props change which is weird

Comment: The only possibility for that is that VideoContainer is constantly remounted. In any other case setLocalStreamEl would be called only once. Consider providing a way to replicate the problem.

Comment: What value does status prop receive and what do you mean by it getting renewed every second

Comment: its a string, a parent component has a one second timer that to display times and other video status info. I figured out the problem, it was the InjectIntl render prop. When I changed it to be a HOC the problem went away. IDK why